# SQLite query of complex data

Tags: python, sqlite

I do experiments where I grow strains of yeast in multiple flasks and take samples I obtain data from for different chemicals.

I've set up a SQLite table with the fields StrainId, FlaskNum, DateTime, HarvestIndex, Species, NumLabeledCarbons, and MDV.

I'm interested in obtaining the MDV data for the earliest sample harvested from each flask for all metabolites in the latest experiment corresponding to that particular strain.

I've written a Python script using the sqlite3 package to retrieve the data I need using a series of for-loops and it works but I suspect there might be a more SQL-centric way to obtain and group the individual data.

Here's what the fetching code basically looks like:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect('fluxData.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    for strainId in cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT StrainId FROM LCMS WHERE StrainId IN ('U','S','UG','SG');").fetchall():
        for dateVal in cur.execute("SELECT max(date(DateTime)) FROM LCMS WHERE StrainId=?",[strainId[0]]).fetchall():
            for flaskNum in cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT FlaskNum FROM LCMS WHERE StrainId=? AND date(DateTime)=?",[strainId[0],dateVal[0]]).fetchall():
                for harvestIndex in cur.execute("SELECT min(HarvestIndex) FROM LCMS").fetchall():
                    for species in cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT Species FROM LCMS WHERE StrainId=? AND date(DateTime)=? AND FlaskNum=? AND HarvestIndex=?",[strainId[0],dateVal[0],flaskNum[0],harvestIndex[0]]).fetchall():
                        print '\n'
                        for row in cur.execute("SELECT NumLabeledCarbons,MDV FROM LCMS WHERE StrainId=? AND date(DateTime)=? AND FlaskNum=? AND HarvestIndex=? AND Species=? ORDER BY NumLabeledCarbons",[strainId[0],dateVal[0],flaskNum[0],harvestIndex[0],species[0]]).fetchall():
                            print row
```

After I obtain the data I group data with the same species and then average them within each group with the same strain.

I'm wondering if this is the best way to do this? Is there a way fetch all of the grouped data using just SQL statements?

Comment: It would be much more helpful to have your database schema then this bunch of for loop and SQL Queries... You use a lot of DISTINCT in your queries which to me is a smell about the fact that your different entity are not properly normalized to ease the way to write the proper query...

Comment: I'm a bit new to SQL so I hope what you're asking for is the columns and the primary key constraint?

Comment: I ran the ".schema LCMS" command and obtained "CREATE TABLE LCMS(StrainId TEXT, FlaskNum INT, DateTime TEXT,HarvestIndex INT, Species TEXT, NumLabeledCarbons INT, MDV REAL, DateTime TEXT, CONSTRAINT LCMSId PRIMARY KEY (StrainId,FlaskNum,HarvestIndex,date(DateTime),Species,NumLabeledCarbons));"

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following SQL aggregate query:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect('fluxData.db')

sql = "SELECT StrainId, FlaskNum, Species, NumLabeledCarbons, MDV, \
       Max(date(DateTime)) As LatestExperimentDate, Min(HarvestIndex) As EarliestHarvest \
       FROM LCMS \
       WHERE StrainId IN ('U','S','UG','SG') \
       GROUP BY StrainId, FlaskNum, Species, NumLabeledCarbons, MDV \
       HAVING DateTime = Max(date(DateTime)) AND HarvestIndex = Min(HarvestIndex) \
       ORDER BY  NumLabeledCarbons;"

with con:
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute(sql)   

   for data in cur.fetchall():
      ...
```

You can then add `Avg()`, `Sum()`, and `Count()` to any numeric columns in the `SELECT` line to compute by group.

Comment: `HAVING HarvestIndex = Min(HarvestIndex)` is pointless. And a simple GROUP BY is not appropriate because the `NumLabeledCarbons` and `MDV` columns are not to be aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the purpose of most of these queries is just to order the result into groups. This can simply be done with ORDER BY.

Getting the latest date for each strain could be done with a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```sql
SELECT NumLabeledCarbons, MDV
FROM LCMS
WHERE StrainId IN ('U','S','UG','SG')
  AND date(DateTime) = (SELECT max(date(DateTime))
                        FROM LCMS AS L2
                        WHERE L2.StrainId = LCMS.StrainId)
  AND HarvestIndex = (SELECT min(HarvestIndex)
                      FROM LCMS)
ORDER BY StrainId, FlaskNum, Species;
```

However, this re-executes the subquery for each row in the table.
It might be more efficient to compute the latest date for each of the four strains in a separate subquery, and join that back to the original table:

```sql
SELECT NumLabeledCarbons, MDV
FROM LCMS
JOIN (SELECT StrainId,
             max(DateTime) AS MaxDate
      FROM LCMS
      WHERE StrainId IN ('U','S','UG','SG')
      GROUP BY StrainId) AS MD
ON LCMS.StrainId       = MD.StrainId AND
   date(LCMS.DateTime) = MD.MaxDate
WHERE HarvestIndex = (SELECT min(HarvestIndex)
                      FROM LCMS)
ORDER BY StrainId, FlaskNum, Species;
```

Answer (score 0):

Method A is Parfait's answer which I've modified a bit to get it to work:

```
SELECT StrainId, Max(date(DateTime)) As LatestExperimentDate, FlaskNum, Min(HarvestIndex) As EarliestHarvest,Species,NumLabeledCarbons,MDV
FROM LCMS
WHERE StrainId IN ('U','S','UG','SG') AND HarvestIndex = (SELECT min(HarvestIndex) FROM LCMS)
GROUP BY StrainId, FlaskNum, Species, NumLabeledCarbons, MDV
HAVING date(DateTime) = Max(date(DateTime))
ORDER BY StrainId, date(DateTime), FlaskNum, HarvestIndex,Species,NumLabeledCarbons;
```

Method B is CL's that I only modified slightly because of ambiguous column name errors:

```
SELECT LCMS.StrainId,date(DateTime),FlaskNum,HarvestIndex,Species,NumLabeledCarbons,MDV
FROM LCMS
JOIN (  SELECT StrainId,max(date(DateTime)) AS MaxDate
        FROM LCMS
        WHERE StrainId IN ('U','S','UG','SG')
        GROUP BY StrainId) AS MD
ON LCMS.StrainId=MD.StrainId AND date(LCMS.DateTime)=MD.MaxDate
WHERE HarvestIndex = (  SELECT min(HarvestIndex)
                        FROM LCMS)
ORDER BY LCMS.StrainId,date(DateTime),FlaskNum,HarvestIndex,Species,NumLabeledCarbons;
```

Method C is my for-loop method above.

I implemented and timed each method to obtain intermediate dictionaries containing all of the data I want and verified that they are all the same.

Also, timed each in seconds over 100 iterations and found methods A, B, and C have means of 0.05831611, 0.05774071, and 0.23839145 seconds, respectively, and respective standard deviations of 0.0071795, 0.00439557, and 0.01499475.

The for-loop method takes about 4 times longer than those proposed by CL and Parfait.

Technically, I was hoping for a way to have the data returned by sqlite3 already divided into NumLabeledCarbons,MDV data for each sample/species combination and for those to be grouped together by species, as opposed to an ordered list of tuples of every single row matching the query. Though I've been told that this isn't the point of SQL.

However, this is much better then the solution I came up with and I've learned quite a lot while trying to understand your answers.

Thank you for taking the time to answer my first Stack Overflow question!